# Gatsby + React Booking Calendar: "WebpackError: ReferenceError: self is not defined "on 'gatsby build' but 'gatsby develop' works fine

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby to build a website. I've added [React Booking Calendar](https://github.com/kristijanbambir/react-booking-calendar/) to display some calendar data.

Running 'gatsby develop' works fine but running 'gatsby build' yields the following error:

```
WebpackError: ReferenceError: self is not defined

  - index.js:13
    node_modules/react-booking-calendar/lib/index.js:13:10310

  - index.js:13
    node_modules/react-booking-calendar/lib/index.js:13:10234

  - index.js:13 e.exports
    node_modules/react-booking-calendar/lib/index.js:13:10505

  - index.js:13 Object.<anonymous>
    node_modules/react-booking-calendar/lib/index.js:13:11026

  - index.js:1 t
    node_modules/react-booking-calendar/lib/index.js:1:328

  - index.js:12 Object.<anonymous>
    node_modules/react-booking-calendar/lib/index.js:12:5444

  - index.js:1 t
    node_modules/react-booking-calendar/lib/index.js:1:328

  - index.js:1 Object.<anonymous>
    node_modules/react-booking-calendar/lib/index.js:1:519

  - index.js:1 t
    node_modules/react-booking-calendar/lib/index.js:1:328

  - index.js:1
    node_modules/react-booking-calendar/lib/index.js:1:401

  - index.js:1
    node_modules/react-booking-calendar/lib/index.js:1:437

  - index.js:1
    node_modules/react-booking-calendar/lib/index.js:1:65

  - index.js:1 Object../node_modules/react-booking-calendar/lib/index.js
    node_modules/react-booking-calendar/lib/index.js:1:211
```

It prints the whole minified version of react-booking-calendar index.js before the error. Searching in that blob, I can see 'self' appears once:

```
f=h(function(){return/msie [6-9]\b/.test(self.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())})
```

I would appreciate any advice on this issue. Thanks.

---

Gatsby version: Gatsby CLI version: 2.12.8
Node version: v13.13.0
React booking calendar: ^1.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Hades points out, Gatsby's behavior may differ between `develop` and `build` due to the assets compilation and JavaScript bundling. You can check for further information in [Gatsby's documentation about debugging](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/).

To bypass your error and compile you have a few options:

- Wait until `window` is defined in your component/function where you use `f=h(function(){return/msie [6-9]\b/.test(self.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())})`. using something like this:

  `if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    f=h(function(){return/msie [6-9]\b/.test(self.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())})
  }`
- Change webpack's configuration to use a `null` loader for your third-party library, using in your `gatsby-node.js`:

  `exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
    if (stage === "build-html") {
      actions.setWebpackConfig({
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /react-booking-calendar/,
              use: loaders.null(),
            },
          ],
        },
      })
    }
  }`
- Place your code inside a `componentDidMount` lifecycle or `useEffect` hook to ensure that the `window` is already defined when you execute the code.

Comment: Thanks. I think option 1 is out because that is in the 3rd party code. 

Option 2 gives me a different error '  Error: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=object&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additi  onal helpful warnings.

  - react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:48 a.b.render
    [windmill]/[react-dom]/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:48:37'

I need to do a little more investigation to try option 3!

Comment: I tried to do option 3 by loading the component in `componentDidMount` but as before, it doesnt work in _gatsby build_ https://gist.github.com/polyglotpiglet/e90634e3c07d8952cfade91f2ee4f373

Comment: Is the package name `react-booking-calendar`?

Comment: The package is `react-booking-calendar` and the react component is `BookingCalendar`. import BookingCalendar from 'react-booking-calendar'; << My attempt at option 3 fails because of the import at the top of my component, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

When running in `develop` you're running a React SPA in the browser mostly.

When running `build` you're running mostly in node, which doesn't know anything about the browser - and you're trying to access `navigator` which is the browser.

Since node has no concept of certain things, such as the DOM, `document`, `window`, etc. you need to use react hooks and state management to access them, and even then it's good practice to check that they exist first.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your answer. I'm not totally clear about the good practice - is it a flaw in this library which I need to work around, or the library is fine and I'm using it wrongly?